# how to drag UIImageView under UIScrollView?

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, uiimageview, touch

I have a UIImageView (imageView) being the subView of the UIScrollView (scrollView). The scrollView is set only for pinching the showed image from imageView. And I have a small UIImageView (iconView) which is the subView of imageView. So the relationship is like:

> ```
> UIView
>  |_____ UIScrollView ( scrollView )
>             |_____ UIImageView (imageView)
>                         |______ UIImageView(iconView) .
> ```

I need to touch and move the iconView but I am confused with this two methods I found.

1. Can I simply use the "hitTest:withEvent:" method to work this out and how to use hitTest ?
2. Or Should I override "UITouchesBegan:withEvent:" "UITouchesMoved:withEvent:" "UITouchesEnd:withEvent:" ? and how to use it?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the 2nd method.

Subclass the UIView class and create CustomView. Define iconView as CustomView.

In CustomView define the 3 delegates to the desired behaviour:

```
UITouchesBegan:withEvent:
UITouchesMoved:withEvent:
UITouchesEnd:withEvent:
```

Hope this helps